# Cannot use rqt_plot to plot ardrone/navdata

Tags: ros, tum-simulator, rqt-plot, ardrone-autonomy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am new to ros. I just starting working with the tum_simulator, ardrone_autonomy and tum_ardrone packages. I am using the simulation in tum_simulator and not an actual drone. I would like to plot ardrone/navdata using rqt_plot. When I tried this I get a blank screen. The command I used was

**$  rosrun rqt_plot rqt_plot /ardrone/navdata**

When I run

**$  rostopic echo /ardrone/navdata**

I get the values. I don't understand why I can't plot the values that I obtain using rostopic echo.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/275630/cannot-use-rqt_plot-to-plot-ardrone/navdata/) by [Ishi](https://answers.ros.org/users/32590/ishi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-11-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

With `rqt_plot` you need specify what data (message attribute) you're trying to plot, as messages can be composed of many other messages (which the `Navdata` message is). If it were to just plot an entire message you could end up with a big mess of plot lines crossing over each other. Besides, some data are strings and arrays. How do you plot a string or an array?

`rostopic` will happily print whatever message it receives because it's not *plotting* the data, just printing out what it receives.

So, to plot the information that you want (altitude for instance) you can use

```
rosrun rqt_plot rqt_plot /ardrone/navdata/altd
```

and then `rqt_plot` will plot the time vs. altitude for you. You can follow the same pattern at the top of `rqt_plot` by entering the topic then specifying the message attribute you want to plot.

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2017-11-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ishi](https://answers.ros.org/users/32590/ishi/) on 2017-11-13**:
I tried what you said and i get the error:
*TopicCompleter.update_topics(): could not get message class for topic type "cvg_sim_msgs/Altimeter" on topic "/altimeter"*

I tried to plot the horizontal velocity vx:
**rosrun rqt_plot rqt_plot /ardrone/navdata/vx**
I got the same error

**Comment by [Ishi](https://answers.ros.org/users/32590/ishi/) on 2017-11-13**:
When I run **rostopic type /ardrone/navdata/vx** I get *ardrone_autonomy/Navdata vx float32*

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-11-13**:
Are you using a simulator or a real drone? That message is telling you that you're missing the `cvg_sim_msgs` package. This error should be solved using another question.

**Comment by [Ishi](https://answers.ros.org/users/32590/ishi/) on 2017-11-13**:
I am using a simulator.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-11-13**:
Did you run

```
source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
```

after compiliing?

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-11-13**:
Also, if you look at https://answers.ros.org/question/72739/cant-plot-some-messages-types-on-rqt_plot/ you'll see that you need to have the message definitions (`cvg_sim_msgs` package) and you may need to restart `rqt_plot` in addition to compiling/`source`ing.

**Comment by [Ishi](https://answers.ros.org/users/32590/ishi/) on 2017-11-13**:
I did run **source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash**

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-11-13**:
Did you install the `cvg_sim_msgs` package?

**Comment by [Ishi](https://answers.ros.org/users/32590/ishi/) on 2017-11-14**:
I installed the tum_simulator package and ran catkin_make. **cvg_sim_msgs** is within the tum_simulator.